# Is there a modern way to do something like Notifications in SwiftUI when you have multiple levels?

Tags: swiftui

Back in the day when you need to control something that is deep on the view hierarchy you could simple use

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver
```

and then post notifications to your objects and they were change.

Now with SwiftUI, if you have just one level of views, you can simple pass the `@State` variable to the next view, that then will do a binding to it.

But imagine a view that is 4 views deep.

```
View A > View B > View C > View D
```

I don't think it would be elegant to pass the `@State` variable 4 levels deep, so `View D` can change it.

Another ugly way would be to create a `@Observable` singleton with a `@Published` variable.

What is the common practice for doing this?

Comment: How about `@Environment`?

Comment: I thought about that, but is this a common practice?

Comment: @Duck yes, relatively so. `@State` vars are generally private or given as a `Binding`, but an `Environment` object is specifically designed to be passed down through a hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SwiftUI has an *environment* system that is designed for this purpose. Values are declared at one point in the SwiftUI view hierarchy – often, but not always, the very top – and are automatically shared with all that views' child views, all their child views, and so on. Views that need to use that data opt in to do so.

Every piece of data in the environment has a distinctive key to set the value at the top and retrieve it where needed.

There are three types of usage:

For **value types** (structs, enums, built-in types like `Int` and `String`) you can create custom `EnvironmentValues` that use a keypath to identify the value.

Setting:

```
MyChildView()
  .environment(\.customProperty, newValue)
```

Using:

```
struct MyChildView {
  @Environment(\.customProperty) var value


  var body: some View {
    Text("Value is \(value)")
  }
}
```

Creating a custom environment key requires a little boilerplate code but it's pretty much the same each time. [This is just one blog post with examples](https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-define-custom-environment-values-in-swiftui/) and there are many more.

For **reference types** (classes), the longstanding way is to make your class conform to `ObservableObject`. Your class's type becomes the key:

```
class MyObject: ObservableObject {
  @Published var name: string
  // etc.
}

struct MyParentView: View {
  var rootObject = MyObject(name: "Foobar")

  var body: some View {
    MyChildView()
      .environmentObject(rootObject)
  }
}

// child view {
struct AnyChildView() {
  // call the variable anything you like – it's the class type that
  // identifies it in the environment
  @EnvironmentObject var myObject: MyObject

  var body: some View {
    Text("Name is \(myObject.name)")
  }
}
```

New in **iOS 17+**, there's an alternative syntax using the new `@Observable` macro that does away with `ObservableObject` and `Published`:

```
@Observable
class MyNewObject {
  var name: string
  // etc.
}

struct MyParentView: View {
  var rootObject = MyNewObject(name: "Foobar")

  var body: some View {
    MyChildView()
      .environment(rootObject) // note, not environmentObject
  }
}

// child view {
struct AnyChildView() {
  // specify the class type in a different way
  @Environment(MyNewObject.self) var myObject

  var body: some View {
    Text("Name is \(myObject.name)")
  }
}
```

Comment: Before asking, I was wondering if that was standard practice, but you've answered brilliantly. Thanks.